# Difference between deg2rad and radians in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Both of the following numpy functions appear to do the same thing.

- [deg2rad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.deg2rad.html)
- [radians](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.radians.html)

What is the difference between the two?
If they are identical,  why have two different function names?

Similarly for `rad2deg` and `degrees`.

Comment: The docs do say that deg2rad was introduced in version 1.13.0 and that the two are equivalent.

Comment: 1.3.0, not 1.13.0

Comment: Yes 1.3.0. Apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 5):

Both functions do exactly the same, but deg2rad is a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions do exactly the same. As I can read inside the code, the function radians calls the function deg2rad. The same is valid for degrees and rad2deg.

So both are doing the same calculation on the same way.

In my view, degrees and radians are still present for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

According to the numpy documentation, the answers by Aliya and thomas should be correct, that the two functions are equivalent. However, I have found that the PyCharm IDE detects a difference. (I'm using PyCharm 2022.3.3 and python 3.10.)

The numpy documentation for rad2deg() and degrees() both state that the return value is of type ndarray, but that "this is a scalar if x (the input angle in radians) is a scalar".

However, when I passed a scalar into degrees(), and then tried to pass the return value into python's round() function, PyCharm gave me an "Unexpected type" warning, suggested that the return value doesn't satisfy "SupportsRound". But when I switched to rad2deg(), PyCharm gave no such warning. This suggests that at some level, there is a difference. Perhaps only in the function signature?